# What is the most pythonic way to compare two variables?

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to write a universal comparison function which can tell that a and b equal  if they have same elements and same amount of them, no matter how these elements are sorted. Moreover I'd like universal solution that can work with all types and in case of type mismatch some message was printed. Example:

```
a = [1, 2]
b = [2, 1]
my_func(a, b)
>>> True

c = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[0, 1],
                  'col2':[2, 3])
d = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1, 0],
                  'col2':[3, 2])
my_func(c, d)
>>> True

my_func(a, c)
>>> Different types to compare!
>>> False
```

Of course, all the checks might be hardcoded, as well as sortings, but I wonder if there is an elegant way to do this.

Comment: http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: You're talking about dataframes... this is not vanilla python

Comment: You raise an `AttributeError`

Comment: Trying to compare different types will always return `False`, if it doesn't raise an `Exception`. It looks like you are trying to cover many bases. Comparing two `Lists` will return `True` *only* if the elements **and their order** is the same. The `DataFrames` you want to compare is a bit more difficult, because it is a more complex type

Comment: @roganjosh well, they stated *any* dataypes, this question isn't really a pandas question. Anyway, I doubt there is a Pythonic way to do this. Python is a strongly typed language, and comparisons between different types should throw an error. I question the wisdom and motivation in creating such a function. In any event, this is not well specified IMO. What exactly is "an element"?

Comment: G_M, about xyproblem - I'd like to track changes of variable by name, however differences in lists and in dataframes could be obtained with different methods, so first I'd like to know whether the type of variable has changed

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga semantics. At the end of the day, the dataframe is not composed of native python structures but, at the base, numpy arrays. The contrasting point of view doesn't get us any closer to being able to answer, though :)

Comment: "I'd like to track changes of variable by name," again, this sounds like an XY problem.  Also, it sounds like bad design if you don't know if f your variable refers to a list or a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

The "pythonic" way to compare things is

```
a == b
```

If you want to compare lists regardless of order, but ensuring they have the same numbers of elements, it's possible to use `collections.Counter`

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(a) == Counter(b)
```